# Localization and Globalization in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

How do I get the current language of user in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture.aspx):

```
var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
```

Which:

> Gets the CultureInfo that represents the current culture used by the Resource Manager to look up culture-specific resources at run time.